# im trying to create gravitational force calculator and i made mistake

Tags: ruby, calculation

I'm trying to create calculator which will calculate the force between two bodies. so here's my code:

```
A_constant = 6.674*10**-11
print "Enter Mass Of The First Object :"
first_num = gets.to_i
print "Enter Mass Of The Second Onject :"
second_num = gets.to_i
print "Enter Distance Between Two Objects :"
third_num = gets.to_i
puts A_constant.to_s + " * " + first_num.to_s + " * " + second_num.to_s + " / " + third_num.to_s + " / " +
      third_num.to_s + " = " +(A_constant * first_num * second_num / third_num / third_num).to_s
```

It works fine but only for inputs like 1,2,3..,10,11,100...11242523 but not for powers like 10^31. at first i thought to write it as 10**31 but it doesn't work. output is same as if input was 10.

Its not serious thing but I'm trying to get into programming so if you could help I'll be thankful.

Comment: [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) interprets the string's characters as an _integer_. It does not interpret the string as a mathematical expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gets` might be not supporting the `**` expression.
To make it work use `eval`, but this may be a bad solution.

```
# F = GMm/R2

GRAVITATIONAL_CONST = 6.674*10**-11

print "Enter Mass Of The First Object :"

mass_of_first_object = gets

mass_of_first_object = eval(mass_of_first_object)

print "Enter Mass Of The Second Onject :"

mass_of_second_object = gets

mass_of_second_object = eval(mass_of_second_object)

print "Enter Distance Between Two Objects :"

distance = gets

distance = eval(distance)

f = GRAVITATIONAL_CONST * mass_of_first_object * mass_of_second_object / (distance * distance)

puts "force: #{f}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are learning, I wont give you the full code. Just sweet pointers ;)

So, ask user what operator they would like to use, like "add", "substract", "power", etc *(case, if, etc)*

Ask the user for inputs to process.

Depending on that, and properly whitelisting the allowed ones, define each options operation.

---

Some hints:

To define operator use, `operator = :**` *(Why a colon sign?)*

Ask for inputs maybe in this fashion, `gets.to_i.public_send(operator, gets.to_i)` *(What is public_send? What if only send? Why a send at all? Why get input this way?)*

Yup, this should help. You will get your calculator and learn some things really neat!

Happy coding ruby.

EDIT - 
*Dont forget to check http://ruby-doc.org/. It gives good explanation.*

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to handle the cases when a user would want to enter `"n^m"` or `"n**m"`. Something like the following could be a start:

```
def parse_input(input)
  return input.to_i unless input.include?("**")
  base, exponent = input.split(/\*\*|\^/).map(&:to_i)
  base ** exponent
end

parse_input("25")
# => 25
parse_input("10**3")
# => 1000
parse_input("10^3")
# => 1000
```

You can then use this method to parse user input and assign the result to your variables:

```
print "Enter Mass Of The First Object :"
first_num = parse_input(gets.chomp)
```

Hope this helps!